# CBV with 2 Mixins that define the same methods - How can I have each Mixin execute its own code?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Edit: Found the same scenario at this question: [Use LoginRequiredMixin and UserPassesTestMixin at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095161/use-loginrequiredmixin-and-userpassestestmixin-at-the-same-time)

My view has 2 Mixins:

```
class FooView(LoginRequiredMixin, EmailVerifiedMixin, View):
        ...
```

`EmailVerifiedMixin` is a `Mixin` I wrote:

```
class EmailVerifiedMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.email_verified

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect(reverse("confirm_account"))
```

The problem is that when an Anonymous user goes to this view, they get redirected to `confirm_account`, rather than my `login_url` from LoginRequiredMixin's handle_no_permission(). See the MRO of this view:

```
>>> pprint(FooView.__mro__)
(<class 'foo_app.views.FooView'>,
 <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin'>,
 <class 'foo_app.views.EmailVerifiedMixin'>,
 <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin'>,
 <class 'django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>,
 <class 'object'>)
>>> FooView.handle_no_permission
<function EmailVerifiedMixin.handle_no_permission at 0x7fbc46d8f1f0>
```

I think the `EmailVerifiedMixin` is just overwriting the `LoginRequiredMixin`'s `handle_no_permission()`? How can I use both of these Mixins?

Just for clarity: The desired behavior is  if the user is not logged in, redirect to `login_url`. If they are logged in, have them go through the `EmailVerifiedMixin`

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it, but it works. Not going to accept my own answer here so please still answer if you know how to do what the question asked.

```
class EmailVerifiedMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.email_verified

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        try:
            login_redirect = super().handle_no_permission()
            return login_redirect
        except PermissionDenied:
            return redirect(reverse("confirm_account"))
```

And just use EmailVerifixedMixin on the FooView now