# How to restrict access to certain groups in django class based view

Tags: python, django, django-views

My `views.py` have a mix of `def` and `ClassViews`:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['Admin', 'Staff', 'Lite Scan'])
def litescan(request):
    filteredOutput = Stock.objects.all()
    val = {}...

@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='login'), name='dispatch')
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community.html'
    ordering = ['-id']
```

And here's my `decorators.py` if that is helpful:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func

def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):

            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                url = ('/forbidden')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

I found out that `@login_required` and `@allowed_users` give out an error when used with `ClassView`. So i used `@method_decorator` which brings me to the login page before redirecting to the page. However, I can not find a way to restrict access to only certain groups like `Admin`, `Staff`, `Lite Scan` with my `ClassView`.

Little help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AccessMixin for your class views.

Example I found:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect 

class FinanceOverview(AccessMixin, TemplateMixin):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            # This will redirect to the login view
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        if not self.request.user.groups.filter(name="FinanceGrp").exists():
            # Redirect the user to somewhere else - add your URL here
            return HttpResponseRedirect(...)

        # Checks pass, let http method handlers process the request
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

More info found here: [Use LoginRequiredMixin and UserPassesTestMixin at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095161/use-loginrequiredmixin-and-userpassestestmixin-at-the-same-time)

Comment: That's fine but when i put `if not self.request.user.groups.filter(name="Admin", "Lite Scan").exists():` it gives out an errot

Comment: I can't put in multiple groups

Comment: Could you use `and`? `if not self.request.user.groups.filter(name="Admin") and not self.request.user.groups.filter(name="OtherGroup")

Comment: `And` did not work but ur suggestion gave me the idea to put the second line after a break and it works fine. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Relying on [Django Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) may be a far simpler approach to giving access to such a view. Rather than checking for a specific list of groups, you can assign permissions to those groups and give access to the view based on whether the user's groups have the appropriate permissions.

> views.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionsRequiredMixin


@permission_required('foo.view_bar')
def my_view(request):
    ...


class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    permission_required = ('foo.view_bar', )
    ...
```